# Make a factory function for creating ko.computed

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm having a little trouble with this concept and I'm wondering if any of you have done this before.

I have a fiddle of my current state of affairs:

http://jsfiddle.net/6xwSY/12/

Do you think there is a way to turn that createRows function into a factory that returns a ko.computed, rather than having my self.itemRows have to declare itself a computed.

Ideally, my code would look like:

```
    self.itemRows = createRows(self.items(), 4);
```

Lemme know what you think, and thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, of course, have a function return a computed observable. In order for the computed to update correctly, though, all observable dependencies need to be "unwrapped" within the computed function. That will require you to change the function to accept an observable array instead of an array.

```
function createRows(itemsObservable, itemsPerRow) {
    return ko.computed(function () {
        var items = itemsObservable() ....
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/6xwSY/13/

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I knew I should have tried to unwrap it. Where does knockout detect that a ko.computed contains an actual observable within it?

Comment: @djk21108 Check out the "How Dependency Tracking Works" section in the [Computed Observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) documentation.

Comment: @djk21108, If I've answered your question, you should accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @GeorgeHowarth thanks for pointing me in that direction. This line really made sense

`While your evaluator function is running, KO keeps a log of any observables (or computed observables) that your evaluator reads the value of.`

Answer (score 1):

Sure, but you will have to [pass in the observable itself instead](http://jsfiddle.net/6xwSY/15/).

```
function createRows(itemsObservable, itemsPerRow) {
    return ko.computed(function () {
        return (function(items, itemsPerRow) {
            var result = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i += itemsPerRow) {
                var row = [];
                for (var j = 0; j < itemsPerRow; ++j) {
                    if (items[i + j]) {
                        row.push(items[i + j]);
                    }
                }
                result.push(row);
            }
            return result;
        })(itemsObservable(), itemsPerRow)
    })
}

self.itemRows = createRows(self.items, 2);
```